# Regex Markdown Matching 1 character

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a simple, simple markdown function (as the CMarkdown parser has issues with my Yii system) however, I am having issues matching the base 1 character markups, like the `#` tag for `<h1>`

```
/**
* Parse string with Simple Markdwon
* @param $text string
* @param $markdown true | false
* @return string
*/
public static function simpleMarkdown($text, $markdown = false) { 

    $simpleMarkdown = array(
                            '/'.preg_quote('###').'{3}(.*)/i',
                            '/'.preg_quote('##').'{2}(.*)/i',
                            '/'.preg_quote('#').'{1}(.*)/i',
                            '/'.preg_quote('###').'{3}(.*)'.preg_quote('###').'{3}/i',
                            '/'.preg_quote('##').'{2}(.*)'.preg_quote('##').'{2}/i',
                            '/'.preg_quote('#').'{1}(.*)'.preg_quote('#').'{1}/i',
                            '/'.preg_quote('***').'{3}(.*)'.preg_quote('***').'{3}/i',
                            '/'.preg_quote('**').'{2}(.*)'.preg_quote('**').'{2}/i',
                            '/'.preg_quote('__').'{2}(.*)'.preg_quote('__').'{2}/i',
                            '/'.preg_quote('*').'{1}(.*)'.preg_quote('*').'{1}/i',
                            '/'.preg_quote('_').'{1}(.*)'.preg_quote('_').'{1}/i',
                            '/'.preg_quote('[c').'{1}(.*)'.preg_quote(']').'{1}(.*)'.preg_quote('[c]').'{1}/i'
                           );
    if ($markdown) {
        $smReplacement = array(
                               '<h3>$1</h3>',
                               '<h2>$1</h2>',
                               '<h1>$1</h1>',
                               '<h3>$1</h3>',
                               '<h2>$1</h2>',
                               '<h1>$1</h1>',
                               '<i>$1</i>',
                               '<i>$1</i>',
                               '<strong>$1</strong>',
                               '<strong>$1</strong>',
                               '<i><strong>$1</strong></i>',
                               '<span style="color:$1">$2</span>'
                              );
    } else {
        $smReplacement = '$1';
    }

    return preg_replace($simpleMarkdown, $smReplacement, $text);
}
```

For example with the input like `##Hello World##` I'll get

```
<h2>Hello World</h2>
<h1></h1>
<h1></h1>
```

New attempts

```
    $simpleMarkdown = array(
                            '/'.preg_quote('#').'{3}(.*)/i',
                            '/'.preg_quote('#').'{2}(.*)/i',
                            '/'.preg_quote('#').'{1}([^#]*)/i',
                            '/'.preg_quote('#').'{3}(.*)'.preg_quote('#').'{3}/i',
                            '/'.preg_quote('#').'{2}(.*)'.preg_quote('#').'{2}/i',
                            '/'.preg_quote('#').'{1}([^#]*)'.preg_quote('#').'{1}/i',
                            '/'.preg_quote('*').'{3}(.*)'.preg_quote('*').'{3}/i',
                            '/'.preg_quote('*').'{2}(.*)'.preg_quote('*').'{2}/i',
                            '/'.preg_quote('_').'{2}(.*)'.preg_quote('_').'{2}/i',
                            '/'.preg_quote('*').'{1}(.*)'.preg_quote('*').'{1}/i',
                            '/'.preg_quote('_').'{1}(.*)'.preg_quote('_').'{1}/i',
                            '/'.preg_quote('[c').'{1}(.*)'.preg_quote(']').'{1}(.*)'.preg_quote('[c]').'{1}/i'
```

And

```
    $simpleMarkdown = array(
                            '/'.preg_quote('#').'{3}([^#]*)/i',
                            '/'.preg_quote('#').'{2}([^#]*)/i',
                            '/'.preg_quote('#').'{1}([^#]*)/i',
                            '/'.preg_quote('#').'{3}([^#]*)'.preg_quote('#').'{3}/i',
                            '/'.preg_quote('#').'{2}([^#]*)'.preg_quote('#').'{2}/i',
                            '/'.preg_quote('#').'{1}([^#]*)'.preg_quote('#').'{1}/i',
                            '/'.preg_quote('*').'{3}([^#]*)'.preg_quote('*').'{3}/i',
                            '/'.preg_quote('*').'{2}([^#]*)'.preg_quote('*').'{2}/i',
                            '/'.preg_quote('_').'{2}([^#]*)'.preg_quote('_').'{2}/i',
                            '/'.preg_quote('*').'{1}([^#]*)'.preg_quote('*').'{1}/i',
                            '/'.preg_quote('_').'{1}([^#]*)'.preg_quote('_').'{1}/i',
                            '/'.preg_quote('[c').'{1}(.*)'.preg_quote(']').'{1}(.*)'.preg_quote('[c]').'{1}/i'
                           );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This time I think I got it for # ## etc:

```
function simpleMarkdown($text, $markdown = false) { 

    $simpleMarkdown = array(
                        '/'.preg_quote('#')."{3}([^#\n]+?)".preg_quote('#').'{3}/i',
                        '/'.preg_quote('#')."{2}([^#\n]+?)".preg_quote('#').'{2}/i',
                        '/'.preg_quote('#')."{1}([^#\n]+?)".preg_quote('#').'{1}/i',
                        '/'.preg_quote('#').'{3}([^#\n]+)/i',
                        '/'.preg_quote('#').'{2}([^#\n]+)/i',
                        '/'.preg_quote('#').'{1}([^#\n]+)/i'
                       );
    if ($markdown) {
        $smReplacement = array(
                           '<h3>$1</h3>',
                           '<h2>$1</h2>',
                           '<h1>$1</h1>',
                           '<h33>$1</h33>',
                           '<h22>$1</h22>',
                           '<h11>$1</h11>',
                           '<i>$1</i>',
                           '<i>$1</i>',
                           '<strong>$1</strong>',
                           '<strong>$1</strong>',
                           '<i><strong>$1</strong></i>',
                           '<span style="color:$1">$2</span>'
                          );
    } else {
        $smReplacement = '$1';
    }

    return preg_replace($simpleMarkdown, $smReplacement, $text);
}

echo simpleMarkdown('#Hello world# #Hello world#', true) . "\n";
echo simpleMarkdown('##Hello world## #Hello world#', true) . "\n";
echo simpleMarkdown('###Hello world### ##Hello world##', true) . "\n";

echo simpleMarkdown("##Hello world\n##Hello world## #Hello world#", true) . "\n";
```

Comment: I think this also the issue, but could be explained a little better. The issue is that you are already listing out 3 `#`s followed by a `{3}` which  means match 3 of the previous character. So you end up with `##` followed by 3 more `#` for a total of 5. Really the patterns altogether are a little messed up. Matching `###.*` will get the entire string, including any trailing `#`.

Comment: I edited my answer to show you the problem. I changed the order because the more specific need to be in first position and less specific at last. If you want to understand why h1 and h2 are imbriqued, try to execute this in a for loop: `return preg_replace($simpleMarkdown, $smReplacement, $text, 1);` and display the text each time

Comment: Preg replace should be making numerous replacements. Wouldn't this not limit only one markdown tag per post? Lol

Comment: When editing the quotes to only one character, I get a output with `<h3></h3><h2></h2><h1></h1>` trailing the correct `<h3>`

Comment: I will update my code but before I must make some test... Some problems with the h3 second case (only starting with ###)

Comment: Most of your `.*` should be `.*?` to force the matches to be non greedy. Greedy means it will find everything up until the last match, non greedy means it will match up to the first match. For example, `#abc# #abc#`. `/#.*#/` will match `#abc# #abc#` where the non greedy `/#.*?#/` will match only the first group like `#abc#`.

Comment: The case where line begin with # or ## or ### is a little bit specific because you must match to the end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

you have to avoid matching more than one # so instead of matching `(.*)` you can try this:

```
#([^#]+)#[^#]
```

This will match any char that is not #, also

```
'/#([^#]+)#[^#]/g'
```

You can test here
https://regex101.com/r/aV8rJ0/5

UPDATED!!!

Comment: I added `([^#]*)` for the single pound and asterisk matches but I end up with 3 `<h1>` tags instead of two. If I add it to all elements I get one giant H3 tag with all content in it.

Comment: actually maybe you should add the single line modifier to make the regex less greedy and if you don't want multiline headlines anyhow? https://regex101.com/r/aV8rJ0/3

Comment: now i think i got it :) https://regex101.com/r/aV8rJ0/5 i added `[^#]` to the last # which avoids any selects where there are more # chars following!!! and it works multi-line too

Comment: Oh I think I know where we're getting off. I do want it to match all types, and change them, but not all types within one tag like `###Hello World###`